# Angular 2 Change Detection With Properties

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a couple questions about properties and change detection with Angular 2.  The main question is are there any concerns about using a property as a bindable property in Angular 2?  Coming from a C# background I'm used to doing something like :

```
 private a: int;
 public get A() : int { return this.a; }
```

The piece that concerns me is that by binding to 'A' I'm basically creating change detection against a function and not a field.  Is this a bad thing?  Also is there any guidance from Google on the use of private fields and properties?

Thanks!

Comment: No problem, but I wouldn't apply C# habits to TypeScript development, where the conciseness of the code matters. Use getters when they're needed. And use lowerCamelCase for your properties.

Comment: Thanks, I kind of guessed that was the style focus for Typescript.  However, what about the binding to the results of a function vs actual data?

Comment: As I said, no problem doing that.